# Missing "Move to Dropbox" contextual menu option

Tags: macos, finder, dropbox

A while ago, I lost the "Move to Dropbox" option in my Finder's contextual menu, and, originally, I didn't make much of it since I read that it was an issue/bug in OS X, which Dropbox reported to Apple. I recently installed Dropbox on my work Mac and noticed that the option displays as expected, so I'm trying to restore it on my home Mac.

EDIT: Image for reference
[image]

I'm currently running Sierra beta 5, but the issue also occurred in El Capital. So far, I've tried the following coupled with killing the Finder process each time:

- Toggling the Finder integration via Dropbox
- Uninstalling Dropbox with AppCleaner and reinstalling
- Deleting ~/.dropbox folder
- Deleting ~/Dropbox/.dropbox.cache folder
- Deleting /Library/DropboxHelperTools folder, which Dropbox recreated
- Toggling Finder integration in System Preferences > Extensions
- Toggling System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > Folder Actions Setup...
- Disabling (and later re-enabling) csrutil
- Restarting Mac

The latest version of Dropbox doesn't have the "Fix Permissions" option anymore, so I can't try that, but I have in the past. What I find strange is that the contextual menu options *within* the Dropbox folder display as expected, while not in my local folders.

As you can tell, I've done my research to no avail, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What contextual menu?

Comment: @Peanut I added an image for reference.

Comment: What appears under Services in the menu?

Comment: @Peanut Share? Various first- and third-party apps, but not Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the contextual menu option only displays within folders on the primary drive. Since my Documents, Downloads, etc. folders are on a secondary drive, it doesn't display, despite the fact that my Dropbox folder is also on this secondary drive.